# Google sheets ARRAYFORMULA + SUMIFS when working with dates

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

im trying to figure out how can i use an arrayformula + SUMIFS when working with dates

Here is a demo sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ttoA9EfMdYJHolcRVrLfpDA2GqYtt19gJruDogzGSf8/edit?usp=sharing

what i need :

in column O I need the balance overdue by client when the date of the payment < today()
I need an arrayformula since is a very big data set

trying to use arrayformula + sumifs does not expand

trying to use arrayformula + sumif and using the & symbol is not working maybe because I need only when is < today ()

```
={"overdue";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), (SUMIF(R:R&A:A,Q:Q&"<"&TODAY(),V:V))-M2:M ,))}
```

im looking for an alternative to this, any help will be very much apreciatted

Thank you !

Comment: If an array formula does not expand, it usually means that the cell below it are not empty. What are the results you would expect to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet. The following array formula is in O2:

`=ArrayFormula({"Overdue"; IF(A2:A="",, MMULT( TRANSPOSE(U2:U) * (TRANSPOSE(Q2:Q)=A2:A) * (TRANSPOSE(P2:P)<=TODAY() ),SEQUENCE( ROWS(U2:U), 1, 1, 0)) - M2:M)})`

A virtual array is formed between the curly brackets { }.

The header is set first (which can be changed within the formula as you like).

If any cell in A2:A is null, then the corresponding cell in O2:O will also be null.

`MMULT` performs `M`atric `MULT`iplication. Here, I've used it to multiply a `TRANSPOSE`d version of the amounts in U2:U by two `TRANSPOSE`d conditional statements (each of which will result to a 1 of TRUE or a 0 if FALSE). If both statements are TRUE, then the value from U2:U will remain (i.e., X * 1 * 1); but if either statement is FALSE, then the result for that row of U2:U will be 0 (e.g., X * 0 * 1 *-or-* X * 1 * 0 *-or-* X * 0 * 0).

The conditional statements check 1.) to see if the client name is the same as the current row; and 2.) to see if the date is less than or equal to TODAY().

It is important that these three readings be `TRANSPOSE`d, in order to form a 2D virtual grid.

The remaining values after the above process will be in virtual horizontal rows parallel to each actual row. These form the first matrix.

The second matrix is formed with `SEQUENCE` and is simply a stack of the number 1 as tall as the number of rows from A2:A in the sheet.

Since anything times 1 is the original number, all 0 or value results from the first matrix are returned *and then added* (which is the function of `MMULT`).

From this, the value in M2:M can be subtracted.

Answer (score 1):

> I need an arrayformula since is a very big data set

The `mmult()` function will error out when the dataset exceeds 3162 rows. To avoid that, use `vlookup()` and `query()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    "Overdue";
    iferror( 
      vlookup( 
        A2:A, 
        query( 
          Q2:V, 
          "select R, sum(V) 
           where Q <= date" & text(today(), " 'yyyy-MM-dd' ") & "
           group by R", 
          0 
        ), 
        2, false 
      ) 
      - M2:M 
    ) 
  } 
)
```

See the [doubleunary](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ttoA9EfMdYJHolcRVrLfpDA2GqYtt19gJruDogzGSf8/edit#gid=837462533) sheet.

Comment: The best answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to subtract clients who are earlier alphabetically and client/dates which are later alphabetically from the total, still using sumif:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="",,sum(V2:V)-sumif(R2:R,"<"&A2:A,V2:V)-sumif(R2:R&Q2:Q,">"&A2:A&today(),V2:V)-M2:M))
```

[image]

Comment: I see that a version of my formula has been pasted into the 'Copy of S2' sheet. Unfortunately I only got as far as testing it on two rows earlier today and ran out of time - have updated the sheet with the full-column formula as given above.